# Cantidad de OR que puedo colocar en una misma consulta

Tags: sql, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Cuantos **OR** puedo colocar en una misma consulta, estoy haciendo una consulta con 4 variables, pero solo me reconoce 3.

Aquí mi formula:

`=QUERY(Data!A2:L73, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L WHERE C ='"&B2&"' or F = '"&D2&"' or B = '"&F2&"'" or D = '"&I2&"'")`

Comment: Hola y [bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), describe tu problema con mas detalle. lee [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Hay algo mas que puedas compartir en tu pregunta? *(código, enlaces de investigación, descripción de lo que hayas intentado, etc)*. Sin mas información, es difícil que la comunidad entienda tu pregunta.

Comment: por favor añade etiquetas especificando qué tecnología estás usando. ¿Excel acaso?

Comment: ¿Eso que es, `Excel`?

Comment: es en Google Sheet,

Comment: La columna D lo que me consulta es una fecha...de mes/año..

Answer (score 1):

QUERY no tiene límites de `OR`.

Quizás el problema se deba a que en la columna estés combinando datos de diferentes tipos, por decir, tienes algunas celdas con fecha pero otras con números. QUERY infiere un tipo de dato para cada columna, los datos que no corresponden al dato inferido son ignorados (los considera como celdas vacías).